# C++ use iostream inside class

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, cout

I'm using `iostream` and `map`. When I try to set the functions, they throw an error.

My code:

```
#include "string"
#include "iostream"
#include "map"

using namespace std;

class myClass {
    map<string, string> Map;
    Map["Ziv"] = "Sion";

    cout << Map["Ziv"];
};
```

My error:

```
error: 'Map' does not name a type
error: 'cout' does not name a type
```

Why I can't use `iostream` and `cout`?

Comment: `main` should be a function, not a class.

Comment: Change `class main` to `int main()`.

Comment: But I want to make a class

Comment: This isn’t the problem, but `#include` directives for standard library headers should use angle brackets, not quotes. So, `#include <string>`.

Comment: @ZivSion "_But I want to make a class_" Doesn't matter what you want: 1) `main` entry point is always a free-standing function. 2) all executable code needs to be in a function. Even if said function is a member of a class.

Comment: `main` can't be a class.  It has to be a function.  What you have here isn't a class anyway; it's just a function that you've tried to call a class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why I can't use iostream and cout?

Because a class cannot (directly) contain expression statements. It can contain only member declarations.

Expression statements can only be within functions. This would be correct for example:

```
class main {
    map<string, string> Map;

    void example_function() {
        Map["Ziv"] = "Sion";
        cout << Map["Ziv"];
    }
};
```

Comment: @ZivSion _"I am pretty new"_ Then this should interest you: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: So this is not a good question and should have been closed (or tagged duplicate) but because the OP set a bounty, it now lead to a +9 answer. IMHO This seems like something inherently wrong with the site...

Answer (score 0):

you can't have a C++ progran without the main function so please create `int main(){}`. And change the double quotes in the `#include` directives to angle brackets like below:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class myClass {
    public:
         int myFunc();
};

myClass :: int myFunc(){
       map<string, string> Map;
       Map["Ziv"] = "Sion";

       cout << Map["Ziv"]; 
}

int main(){
myClass myclass;
myclass.myFunc();

return 0;
}
```

Please consider i am a beginner and forgive my mistakes if any.

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @GaryNLOL ```using namspace std;``` is considered bad practice because when we have a complex program with multiple namespaces ```using namespace std;``` can lead to confusion regarding methods of the ```std``` namespace and other namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented languages, like C++, you can't write expressions/statements in a class. You may want to use a function. Example:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;

class Example {
public:
   void sayHello() {
      cout << "Hello!";
   }   
}

int main() {
   new Example().sayHello(); // Prints Hello!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter the cout in a function, inside the class you can't execute functions, you just can describe them or variables / objects.

Answer (score 0):

Class is an Entity which contains related data members and the operations to modify or access those data members. No expression can be executed within the class. It does not make an sense to do something that you can not access. Because the only way to access and modify something are operations.

Yes in case if you want to print something when the class object is created, you can do that in Constructor. May be this is what you want to do:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class myClass {
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::string> Map;
public:
    myClass(const std::string& key, const std::string& value){
        Map[key] = value;
        std::cout << value;
    }
};

int main(){
    myClass cls("Ziv", "Sion");
}
```